# monodevelop ubuntu c# appindicator

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop, appindicator

I am just starting out with Mono-GTK app development. I wanted to setup a appindicator icon in systray. But C# returns namespace is missing.

code:
using AppIndicator;

returns error:
The type of namespace name 'AppIndicator' could not be found.Are you missing directive or an assembly reference?

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator0.1-cil-dev
```

And then compile with

```
dmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0,appindicator-sharp-0.1 file.cs
```

Comment: am really sorry, didnt notice the answer. Was very busy for last week or so. Will try it now and respond quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following:

1. `sudo apt-get install libappindicator0.1-cil-dev`
2. Then add a reference to the library (see image below)
3. Finally, include a reference to namespaces you need. Typically these will be the following:

   `using AppIndicator;`

   `using Gtk;`

   `using System;`

[image: Edit References].